# jQuery sortable disable first placeholder

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way I can disable the first placeholder in a sortable unordered list?

I still want to be able to sort the first item (i.e. all items should be draggable), but I don't want any of the items after the first one to be able to be dropped above the first.

I have this sort of working but instead of having the first placeholder disabled, when an item is dropped the sort is cancelled:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.placeholder.index() <= 1) {
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        } else {
            //sort item
        }
    }
});
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. Your code was not that far from my solution.

The idea is to use `change` option to show/hide placeholder depending on its position and to cancel drop if position is the first.

The code ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s9NVZ/)):

```
var cancelRequired = false;
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.placeholder.index() < 1) {
            $(ui.placeholder).css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $(ui.placeholder).css('display', '');
        }
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        cancelRequired = (ui.placeholder.index() <= 1);
    },
    stop: function() {
        if (cancelRequired) {
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
});
```

The hack used in `beforeStop` and `stop` is done because of a bug when trying to call cancel directly inside `beforeStop`. [More info here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/problem-with-sortable-4-10-2010) which send me to [this link](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6054).

This code has been tested with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery-ui 1.9.2

Comment: I've tweaked your code a bit to add a placeholder when an item is dragged above the first item - placeholder appears where the item was originally as this is where is moves back to if dropped above the first item. I'm sure it could be implemented better, but works for me. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsx7M/

Comment: I used your code to do the same thing but for the last item in the list instead of the first. The trick was to test the .index() value against the $("#parent").children().length - 1 to know whether or not you are on the list item in the list.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more simpler way to do it, and by this way the revert function works too.
For this to work, you should add a class to your first item.

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="no_sort sortable_first">First item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    placeholder: 'sortable_placeholder',
    cancel: '.no_sort',
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 100,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.placeholder.index() < 1) {
            $('.sortable_first').after(ui.placeholder);
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8uj4/)